# Minecraft how to get arrows

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need a easier way to get arrows like maybe making one then having infinite arrows.Maybe there's a link you could find and post so that I could watch a video?

Comment: Well we're not about to posts cheats or anything like that for you. But there are plenty of easy ways to legitimately get arrows.

Comment: Not voting to close as this isn't about multiplayer game mode cheating.

Comment: Infinity enchantment.

Comment: Hostile mob farm, while not the easiest way to get arrows, has so many other positive effects it's the best way to approach the problem. More arrows than you'd ever use, tons of rotten flesh for trade, spider eyes for potions, string - for wool, because shearing is a chore, and you'll have more string than you'd know what to do with, gunpowder - for firework rockets which are essential and used copiously once you get Elytra, and XP for enchanting and repairing items.

Comment: Note a lot of mob farm designs on Youtube are obsolete as mobs change AI and stop following the "flow". [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zj4jw2An5xI) is fairly current, cheap, easy and efficient, although you really should replace the 49 hoppers with a cheaper collection system.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to invest the time, you can make yourself an unstoppable archer. There's no 'easy' way to do it, but you can get lucky.

- If you come across a skeleton dungeon, you can create a mob grinder for essentially unlimited arrows. If you use a splash potion of healing to kill them, you can get the XP from them as well.
- If you come across a village, you can potentially get a librarian who sells the infinity enchantment. You can also try your luck at getting the infinity enchantment by placing 15 bookshelves around an enchantment table.
- Librarians can also sell mending enchantment books, which in essence makes your infinity bow have unlimited durability.

Other than that, your best options are to:

- Craft them. Have a chicken farm for feathers, and mine gravel for flint. You can place gravel you've mined for more chances at flint.
- Hunt skeletons at night. Having a tamed wolf helps since they prioritize skeletons (they love dem bones).

Playing through hardcore several weeks ago, I managed to get a Power V/Infinity/Mending bow simply by farming and expanding a village that I found. I continually traded for emeralds, then spent them on high-quality enchantments. It took several hours of farming to do, but nothing could touch me at night - I didn't even need to bring a sword or axe since my bow could kill anything in 1-2 shots.

Comment: I then got myself killed in The End when I was swarmed by Endermen because I looked at a bunch of them and bows do squat against them.

Comment: And a cherry on the cake: `/give @p minecraft:arrow 1` in a always active Repeat command block.